# Bootstrap 4 - Prevent opening of modal when clicked on dropdown button

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I am using BS 4 Modal and my dropdown buttons are placed inside the div which is responsible for modal opening on click:

The problem is I want to prevent the opening of the modal when I clicked on the dropdown button

Here is my [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ceugLy1/)

```
$("#addEventsButton").on('click', function(event) {
    $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');

})
```

Comment: I don't see any dropdown inside your fiddle? Can you please elaborate on your problem statement?

Comment: @BharatChoudhary Updated my fiddle

Comment: And what is the reason behind nesting the dropdown inside the `div` which you bound click event to? You can simply take the `#dropdown` div out of `#addEventsButton` div and your problem is solved.

Comment: @rmalviya u r right but sorry I can go back bacause the design and functionality is almost completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this code snippet.

```js
$("#addEventsButton").on('click', function(event) {
 $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show');
})
```

```css
.adiv {
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha256-fTuUgtT7O2rqoImwjrhDgbXTKUwyxxujIMRIK7TbuNU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha256-pl1bSrtlqtN/MCyW8XUTYuJCKohp9/iJESVW1344SBM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" integrity="sha256-Nfu23DiRqsrx/6B6vsI0T9vEVKq1M6KgO8+TV363g3s=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<!-- Button trigger modal -->

<div class="adiv">

<p id="addEventsButton">
 Click me to open the modal
</p>
    
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="marker" value="r1">
        
        <input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="marker" value="r2">
        
        <input type="radio" class="new-control-input" name="marker" value="r3">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="add-e" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only change I made is, moved the id `addEventsButton` from parent `div` tag to `p` tag

```
    <p id="addEventsButton">
 Click me to open the modal
</p>
```

Comment: @owaiz, if this solution solved your issue, why don't you accept it as an answer.

Comment: @OwaizYusufi, are you fine with moving the id to p tag?

Answer (score 1):

This happend because you added the dropdown menu into your modal click "div" tag... 
If you close "" tag just before that "dropdown" div tag then it might solve your problem... 
But this change your html view ..

```
<div id="addEventsButton" class="adiv">
<br>
<p>
 Click me to open the modal
</p>
</div>    <!-- Add this tag here -->

<div class="dropdown">
```

Just let me know you not expecting these layout or simply modify the css